# UnicodeEncodeError when saving pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, export, export-to-csv

I'm trying to use one Export function for multiple dataframes:

```
def Export_df(df, path):
    df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\yannick.haussmann\\Desktop\\"+path, sep=";", index=False,encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

When I call this function inside another one like this:

```
Export_df(df,"NEW_TERM.csv")
```

why do I get the following error?

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 369: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Comment: Why do you explicitly set the encoding? If you leave it at the default value 'utf-8', does it work? I.e. if you remove the encoding argument altogether.

Comment: Somewhere in your dataframe you have a unicode "EN DASH" character ` '–'` instead of the base ascii DASH and that can't be converted to latin-1. If you really need latin-1 (the world is unicode these days) then you'll need to scrub the data before it goes into the data frame. So, the question is, can you switch output to utf-8 or utf-16?